# How can I remove the root node and make the first child the new root node with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

How can I transform some XML with XLST, so that the first direct child node of the current root node becomes the new root node.

So for example given the following XML:

```
<Envelope>
  <Nodes>
    <Node1>
      <ChildNode>lorem</ChildNode>
    <Node1>
    <Node2>
      <ChildNode>lorem</ChildNode>
    <Node2>
  </Nodes>
</Envelope>
```

Should become:

```
<Nodes>
  <Node1>
    <ChildNode>lorem</ChildNode>
  <Node1>
  <Node2>
    <ChildNode>lorem</ChildNode>
  <Node2>
</Nodes>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a rule to the identity transform that adds nothing to the result tree for your document element other than the processing of its children:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(edited to be agnostic to the name of the document element)

(edited again to only preserve the first child element of the document element)

Comment: This would include *all* children of an envelope element, not just the first and would do it regardless of where that element was in the document.

Comment: Granted, yes ... I missed that original requirement.  I'll change it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything fancy, just match the root (`/*`) and make a `copy-of` the first child (`*[1]`).

This is a case where a simple inbuilt command can be used to do whats needed, rather than using the identity transform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

edit: Corrected root selector as per  G. Ken Holman and  Sean B. Durkin's comments.

Comment: As you have it written now, you are matching on the root node and copying the first child element, which is the document element, so the output would be the same as the input.  I suspect you want to match on `/*` as I have it and not `/` as it reads now.  Your use of `<xsl:copy-of>` would be faster than the piecemeal copy I'm doing.

Comment: @G.KenHolman No, `/` matchs on the document root node (and is no different to `/*`), the `copy-of` copies the first child element of the root node. This is exactly what the question asked for in the clearest and shortest possible way. Its been tested and works as described.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr : Holman is right. You can test this very easily. All you need to put it right is an extra `*` in your match condition.

Comment: @G.KenHolman I stand corrected you are correct. My eyes must have skipped a line when I looked over the output in the test I did. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove envelope from messages there is a much more elegant way than XSLT: you can define a so-called envelope schema and let the XML disassembler pipeline component know that the messages are packed in this kind of envelope. From this point the envelope will be automatically removed once a message is received. It is good because you don't have to develope, deploy and maintain maps.